# Magento 2 - Unable To pass multiple parameters from phtml to a JavaScript component using x-magento-init

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am unable To pass multiple parameters from phtml to a JavaScript component using x-magento-init.

Below is my init script. I am able to send the first param (it's a simple variable). the second param is the form key. If I also try to send it as a second param an error occurs.

**below is my Script:**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
        "*": {
            "test_TestModel/js/ordereditems-modal": {
                "numberItems": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $numberItems; ?>,
                "formKey": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Below is the **'ordereditem-modal.js'** script to receive it:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($,modal) {
    'use strict';

        return function (config) {

            $(document).ready(function () {

      ....do something 

   
            });
        }
    }
);
```

i drew inspiration for this from [/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/02e0378c33054acb0cdb8d731d1e2b2c2069bc1b/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml#L76-L85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know the error you are receiving.

It is likely that it is because you have forgot the quotes on your `formKey` value. Try this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
        "*": {
            "test_TestModel/js/ordereditems-modal": {
                "numberItems": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $numberItems; ?>,
                "formKey": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

To test it add `console.log(config);` in your script.

Comment: Hey Ben. your solution worked. thank very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can check using below code.

```
<?php
    $customFormKey = $block->getFormKey();
?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "test_TestModel/js/ordereditems-modal": {
                "numberItems": "<?= /* @noEscape */ (int)$numberItems ?>",
                "formKey": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $customFormKey ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note:** You can also add form key using Object Manager, however is not recommended

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $obFormKey = $objectManager->get('YOUR_VENDOR_NAME\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Data\Form\FormKey');
?>
```

Then pass it in your script as below

```
...
"formKey": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $obFormKey ?>"
...
```